# Adding custom filter for asset publisher portlet?

Tags: portlet, liferay, portal, liferay-6

We have created a new template and structure with custom attributes for submitting web content. The structure has few list attributes like:

```xml
<dynamic-element name='size' type='list' index-type='' repeatable='false'>
<meta-data>…</meta-data>
<dynamic-element name='Less_than_5_000' type='Less_than_5_000' index-type=''     repeatable='false'>  </dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name='5_000_to_10_000_employees' type='5_000_to_10_000_employees' index-type='' repeatable='false'> </dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name='10_000_to_20_000_employess' type='10_000_to_20_000_employess' index-type='' repeatable='false'></dynamic-element>
</dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name='location' type='list' index-type='' repeatable='false'>
<meta-data>…</meta-data>
<dynamic-element name='Central_West' type='Central_West' index-type='' repeatable='false'>  </dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name='South' type='South' index-type='' repeatable='false'>      </dynamic-element>
```

To display these contents I am using Asset-publisher, category navigation and tags portlet. This requires categories creation and assignment when content is published. The Asset publisher portlet provides capability to filter content on the basis of categories and does not support filtering based on custom attributes like one defined in structure above. 
Is there a way to display content based on custom attributed defined in structure using asset publisher? 
For example can we – 
a.  Display all contents where employees are “Less than 5000”?
b.  Display all contents where employees are “Less than 5000” and Location is “South”?

Answer (score 0):

I completely don't understand what you're trying to do with that structure, e.g. the type "Less_than_5_000" IMHO shows some wrong understanding of structures: Rather have a field "companySize", maybe as an option list.

If you need more pointers on finding your content, there's [a nice blog post on how to use the Templates to interface with Liferay's API](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/advanced-web-content-example-with-ajax), also you might want to think about automatically tagging/categorizing your content based on some criteria - e.g. by overriding the Web Content Services: Whenever an article is stored you could run your own code and categorize the article automatically in order to use the stock AssetPublisher.

Also, of course, you could customize AssetPublisher or provide a simple portlet that does exactly what you want: Make it as simple as possible to meet exactly your needs. Should be a small & easy to maintain portlet that filters the articles you need, utilizing Liferay's API.

Comment: We have achieved this by using asset publisher and categories navigation portlets. IPC works using categoryId and with the help of a hook we could get what we wanted.